# How to set Java classpath in Linux?

Tags: linux, classpath

I downloaded `apache-log4j-1.2.16.zip` and unziped it. I then renamed it as `LOG4J_HOME` and placed it in `/home/appnetix` folder which is my folder. I tried setting the classpath in the terminal using the following command :

```
[appnetix@Sanjeev ~]$ set classpath=%path%;LOG4J_HOME/log4j-1.2.16.jar;
```

That returned:

```
bash: LOG4J_HOME/log4j-1.2.16.jar: Permission denied
```

I tried doing this:

```
[appnetix@Sanjeev ~]$ set classpath=%path%;//home/appnetix/LOG4J_HOME/log4j-1.2.16.jar;
```

But I got this:

```
bash: //home/appnetix/LOG4J_HOME/log4j-1.2.16.jar: Permission denied
```

Please help, I'm new in Linux (one month).

Answer (score 32):

```
export CLASSPATH=/home/appnetix/LOG4J_HOME/log4j-1.2.16.jar
```

or, if you already have some classpath set

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/home/appnetix/LOG4J_HOME/log4j-1.2.16.jar
```

and, if also you want to include current directory

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/home/appnetix/LOG4J_HOME/log4j-1.2.16.jar:.
```

Answer (score 25):

You have to use ':' colon  instead of ';' semicolon.

As it stands now you try to execute the jar file which has not the execute bit set, hence the Permission denied.

And the variable must be CLASSPATH not classpath.

Answer (score -3):

Can you provide some more details like which linux you are using? 
Are you loged in as root? 
On linux you have to run export CLASSPATH = %path%;LOG4J_HOME/og4j-1.2.16.jar
If you want it permanent then you can add above lines in ~/.bashrc file.

Comment: I would not do it in the .bashrc because it will fight with other projects/programs. Better create a simple script to set the environment and start another shell or whatever you use.