# Can not start Java application via commandline

Tags: java, maven, command-line, console, dependencies

So i have a maven project in eclipse that i can normally start via run as> Java Application. If i however try to start the class file from the target directory from the commandline via "java TestServer" it wont work. It says it cant find or load the main class. If i replace the sourcecode with a simple dummy hello world and execute then it works fine.

The code has two maven dependencies.

Simple dummy:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("hello world!");

    }
}
```

Why does this happen? Is there a problem due to the nestest class? Why can't a main class be found for the code but for a small dummy?

Comment: No need to post a Copyright header with your code here.

Comment: Indeed, from the Legal link at the bottom: *"You agree that all Subscriber Content that You contribute to the Network is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange under the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license. "*

Comment: Its not my copyright im just using the library. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Well ... yes ... kind of.  1) The license you posted potentially conflicts with CCA/SA.  2) If you are posting code written by other people, >>you<< are responsible for ensuring that there is no copyright violation.

Comment: Well it is licensed under the eclipse public license. That should be ok right? Or am i committing a copyright violation? It was a simple example file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the classpath.

Maven is not responsible for running the project from Eclipse workspace
because Eclipse holds its own `.project` file, which contains all classpath entries. When you use `Run As`, Eclipse just uses all classpath configurations of its `.project` file.

To start the java program from console, you need to set the classpath to your `bin` or `target` directory and to all libraries ('jar') which are referenced by your project. After setting the classpath correctly you can start your program with `java <qualified classname>`. Starting the program this way does not use any of Maven's functionallity yet at all.

Have a look here to use Maven https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

Maven will create a library `jar` which contains all classes of your project.
You can set the classpath to the generated library and start your programm using `java <qualified classname>`

EDIT due to comment

Here is an example for setting the classpath using the Windows OS 
console. You can put this line also into an appropriate Windows batch (.bat)
file and start your program,

```
set classpath = .;log4j.jar;lib/any-other-lib.jar
java org.<whatever>.MyProgram
```

for further information for setting the classpath on other OS's you may also have a look at 
[setting Java Classpath in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973624/setting-java-classpath-in-linux)

Comment: EDit NVM i just read that you need to add all referenced libraries to the classpath too. That explains why the dummy works but the actual code does not.

Comment: the simplest way is to open a console. Switch to the target (bin) directory and call set classpath = .;<reference1.jar>;<reference2.jar>;.. Where the dot sets the classpath to the current directy and the rest to the associated jar files.

Comment: Do you import any other library right now. E.g log4j.jar or something like that

Comment: @Siniyas correct. you can concatenate the referenced libraries using a semicolon " ; "

Comment: That's not how you set the classpath on linux or MacOSX ... and I think it is not even correct on windoze.  For a start, environment variable names are case sensitive.

Comment: @Stephen don't understand your question. But you are right when you mention any differences concerning the OS. This example shows a windows batch invocation of setting the classpath. On Linux and Mac it might be different due to the appropriate bash commands and of course a .bat must be replaced there with an .sh file

Comment: I thought that Windows environment variables were case sensitive.  Apparently not.