# How to install jdbc in CentOS and use package in python function?

Tags: python, jdbc, centos

I am  new to working out of a linux instance when coding. I am using CentOS and am working on a python script that depends on connecting to SQL Databases. The function that I have written that connects to can be seen below:

```
import jaydebeapi
import pandas as pd 
import json 
from query import p1

def get_conn(conn_name, conf_file = 'data.json' ):
    conf_dict = json.load(open(conf_file, 'r'))
    c = conf_dict[conn_name.lower()]
    return (jaydebeapi.connect(jclassname=c['driver_name'], url=c['jdbc_url'],
                driver_args=[c['user'], c['passwd']])
           )

conn_scd = get_conn('ora_pdmsn')
scd_df = pd.read_sql(p1, conn_scd)
conn_scd.close()

print(scd_df)
```

This results in a error of:

`TypeError: Class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SqlServerDriver is not found`

I have tried finding the correct way to install this driver in centOS but nothing seems to be working. Any advice? A sample of what my JSON.data looks like can be seen below:

```
{"mssql":
    {   "conn_name":"ora_pdmsn", "driver_name":"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
        "jdbc_url":"internal_url",
        "user":"name", "passwd":"pass",
        "test_sql":"select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as ts"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jaydebeapi needs access to the relevant JAR (Java archive) file which contains the JDBC driver you want to use. You therefore need to ensure the JDBC driver is on the Java classpath, so jaydebeapi can use it when you run your program.

This also means you need to have Java installed, of course. The `java -version` command can check for you.

---

Do you have the relevant JDBC JAR file already? The one you need depends on:

- the version of MS-SQL Server you are using, and
- the version of Java you have installed

You can download versions of the driver [from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15). This gives you version 9.2 of the driver, in 3 different files, for 3 versions of Java (8, 11 and 15).

(If you have an older version of SQL Server, this version of the JDBC driver may not work for you.)

Unzip the zip file and locate the JAR files in the `sqljdbc_9.2/enu` directory. The name of the JAR file indicates the version of Java that it supports:

```
mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre8.jar
mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre11.jar
mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre15.jar
```

After you have the correct JAR file, you can refer to its location directly in your Python connection code, as an extra parameter.

Here is my version of doing that (using MySQL, in my case, as I do not have MS-SQL Server) - where I have not used a JSON file, for simplicity:

```py
jaydebeapi.connect("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver",
                   "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db",
                   ["myuser", "mypass"],
                   "/path/to/mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar")
```

Of course, you will want to change all those details from my MySQL details to your MS-SQL Server ones - but note that last value which points to the JAR file.

---

Alternatively you can [set the Java classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973624/how-to-set-java-classpath-in-linux), and use that, instead of prvoiding the JAR file location in your code. In this case, the classpath will point to a directory, and the directory will contain the JAR file. I find this approach less convenient, but it's up to you.

---

Another option for SQL Server JDBC drivers is to use jTDS - see [here](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/). I have used this with older versions of SQL Server with no issues.